# dotnet entity frameworkcore migration command not work in vs 2022

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, visual-studio-2022, ef-core-3.1, dotnetcorecli

While migration in ef core using below command give me an error.

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
```

[image]

After refer this [link](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/19861) , i have executed below command.

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
```

But still give me an error.

[image]

Below packages installed in my project.

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore(3.1.25) ,
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design(3.1.25),
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer(3.1.25), 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools(3.1.25)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the migrations command you need to install the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools Nuget package.

Comment: I have installed Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools and after again execute command still give me an error.

Comment: The exact same?

Comment: Yes same error.

Comment: Interesting, see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/migrations. "The EF commands for the PMC commands are in the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools". I have it working here.